# Spring MVC show image

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to show image in my JSP page in my Spring MVC Project , but the images are not working.

The images are located in src/main/webapp/resources/images folder

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoxiX.png)

Please find the code below. Any help will be appreciated:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

// Resource reading from jsp

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

//Here I declare a mapping of src\main\webapp\resources folder and all its content to a resource location value /resources/
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/");

}


// Property reading from jsp
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("/WEB-INF/i18n/application");
    return messageSource;
}


// View Resolver
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    //internalResourceViewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/");
    internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return internalResourceViewResolver;
}
```

}

In the jsp it is called as :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img src="<c:url value='/resources/images/abc.jpg' />" >
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

based on our folder structure resource mapping is changed

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

 //Here I declare a mapping of src\main\webapp\resources folder and all its 
  content to a resource location value /resources/
   registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
   .addResourceLocations("/resources/");

}
```

Comment: I have edited what you suggested , but still no luck                          @Override
 public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

  registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
  
 }

Comment: I thought you are having a problem with your folder structure

Comment: Could you please suggest what would be the structure ?

Answer (score 0):

**ResourceResolvers** can resolve resources, given their URL path. They can also resolve the externally facing public URL path for clients to use, given their internal resource path.

XML configuration:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

Annotation Configuration:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

Use in jsp:

```
<img src="/contextpath/resources/images/abc.jpg" >
```

Resource folder structure in project:

```
TestProject
|
src
|
WebContent
         |
          resources
                  |
                   js/css/images
```